# what status the server will be if there is no such file like /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts

Tags: linux, config, icmp

`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts` file in linux determine whether ICMP broadcast is ignored or not. when it's value is 1,system ignore incoming ICMP broadcast . 
So here is my question :
when there is no icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts  file in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/` directory ,or there is no value in this file ,what the server's status will be? will ICMP broadcast be ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value is documented in the kernel source here:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.2-rc5/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt#L816-L819

```
icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts - BOOLEAN
    If set non-zero, then the kernel will ignore all ICMP ECHO and
    TIMESTAMP requests sent to it via broadcast/multicast.
    Default: 1
```

So it defaults to `1`. I'm not sure if there's a way to confirm that from the command line. Maybe this?

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts
```

But unless your distro customizes this value, it seems safe to assume the value is `1`.

Comment: Thank for your instant help especially the link you provide really do me a lot of favor !